# What is the best structure to create a data with different values numbers in each row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

so I have unique categories with different number of elements
the 1st category has 3 elements and the 2nd category has 4...so on
but the structures I tried required that the rows have the same number of values
I tried the dataframe from pandas didn't work:

```
data = { 'func1': [[0.25, 33, 12], [12, 0, 50], [100, 25, 1]],
    'func2': [[33, 2, 15], [12, 0, 50]] }
```

I also tried the numpy array but it kept showing this VisibleDeprecationWarning:

```
td= np.array([[[1.22,7],[20,0]],[[0.4,5]],[[7,9],[4,3]]])
```

Can you suggest a structure that can help me create rows with uneven number of values/elements?

What I want to do is the following after creating the data I want:

1. Am going to randomly choose an element in each category
2. Then I will create a matrix with same rows and columns as the data
   (if that's possible) and put 1 in the location of the element chosen
   and 0 in the elements chosen

for now that's what am going for, looking forward to your suggestions

edit: I would also like to be able to access the values of the element